# MVP Android implementation

Tags: android, design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvp

I did some research on MVP articles and examples, but I can not figure out how to apply MVP on my application code. Are there specific guidelines for a proper MVP implementation for Android.
and if there are examples a same application with MVC and MVP.

and thank you :)

Comment: Example can be found here https://android.jlelse.eu/android-mvp-for-beginners-25889c500443

Comment: instead, here are some guidelines on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this is good to read about MVP 
https://medium.com/@cervonefrancesco/model-view-presenter-android-guidelines-94970b430ddf

Comment: In this article I show how to use MVP for building a simple movie search app together with complete Github sample. Hope it helps: http://www.digigene.com/mvp-easymvp-wolfkcats

Comment: hey man, there is a sample project implementing MVP in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXDAcWEhYSk&t=14s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google architecture samples is a good way to start with MVP.

1. Clone [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/) repository.
2. Read the code and try to understand.
3. Try to replicate similar thing in your project.
4. Don't be afraid to shamelessly copy & move on even if you don't understand for a while.
5. This is how I did it, with time you will understand what's going on & soon you can fit your requirements accordingly.